# How to get push notification with buttons for android using fcm

Tags: android

I am new to FCM. I successfully send notification and data-messages using fcm but now i need to send notification with two buttons on it..I just want to know is it possible with FCM ?? if yes, How Can I do Such thing.
  Thanks in advance

Comment: you mean custom notification?

Comment: yes, with two buttons

Comment: then use pendind intent with ACTIONBUTTONS in notification.Builder

Comment: In onMessageReceived mehod of FirebaseMessagingService . right ?

Comment: where you display notification. In your Notification builder code:  NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Go", pendingIntent).build();  and .addAction(action)

Comment: bro i know about it but i want to do same thing using FCM

Comment: that is same as creating notifictaion, you receive data using FCM OnmessageReceived right? then get data and create pending intent with it and add as button

Comment: but when app is in background this method is not called at all... and notification is handled by fcm..i got it using data-messages bt i want to know is there any other way to do so ?

Comment: Just a reminder: only data-messages in fcm will make onMessageReceived fired if your app is in background; ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive